# How to sort, hide and show div's based on selection made in selecctbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, hide, show

This might be a bit confusing, but i will try to explain the best i can. 
I have two select boxes and multiple div's with two classes in each. What I wanted to achieve is:

1. When I select a option the div's which have that class should be displayed. Others should be hidden.
2. When I select 'All' all div's should be displayed.
3. Initially all div's should be displayed.

Example:

If I select "OLVR" in first select box, all div's with class 'OLVR' should be displayed.
If I select "New York" in first select box, all div's with class 'NY' should be displayed.

Help me with jquery.

Thanks,
Tharun.

```html
<select id="type">
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="OLVR">OLVR</option>
  <option value="ElectionNight">Election Night</option>
  <option value="Licensing">Licensing</option>
</select>

<select id="location">
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="NY">New York</option>
  <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
  <option value="MX">Mexico</option>
</select>

<div class="NY OLVR all">
  <h1>New York OLVR</h1>
</div>

<div class="NY ElectionNight all">
  <h1>New York Election Night</h1>
</div>

<div class="NY Licensing all">
  <h1>New York Licensing</h1>
</div>

<div class="VT OLVR all">
  <h1>Vermont OLVR</h1>
</div>

<div class="VT ElectionNight all">
  <h1>Vermont Election Night</h1>
</div>

<div class="VT Licensing all">
  <h1>Vermont Licensing</h1>
</div>

<div class="MX OLVR all">
  <h1>Mexico OLVR</h1>
</div>

<div class="MX ElectionNight all">
  <h1>Mexico Election Night</h1>
</div>

<div class="MX Licensing all all">
  <h1>Mexico Licensing</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Apart you have two select inputs and you did not explained how they should perform together, you have also a class `Election Night` and also `ElectionNight` and you did not explained what about them.

Comment: Hi those two select inputs are not connected. They perform separately. And "Election Night" is option text. "ElectionNight" is a value and class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#type, #location").change(function() {
    // Hide div's having all when option changed in the select box.
        $('.all').hide();
    // Show div having value of option as its class.
        $('.' + $(this).find('option:selected').val()).show();
    });

    });

   </script>
```

Use this script in your head part of your HTML

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach I can think of is:

```
// bind a change event-handler, using on():
$('select').on('change', function() {
  // create an array of the selected options' values, with map() and get():
  var vals = $('select').map(function() {
      return $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    }).get(),
  // check if any of the selection option-values is 'all', using
  // Array.prototype.some() (v is the array-element over which we're iterating):
    all = vals.some(function(v) {
      return v === 'all';
    });

// hide all the <div> elements within the .divContainer element:
  $('.divContainer').find('div').hide()
    // return to the original selector:
    .end()
    // if any of the selected values was 'all', we select all <div> elements,
    // otherwise we find the element(s) which are a <div> *and* which have
    // the relevant classes we're looking for (for example: "div.OLVR.NY"):
    .find(all ? 'div' : 'div.' + vals.join('.')).show();
});
```

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  var vals = $('select').map(function() {
      return $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    }).get(),
    all = vals.some(function(v) {
      return v === 'all';
    });

  $('.divContainer').find('div').hide().end().find(all ? 'div' : 'div.' + vals.join('.')).show();
});
```

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="OLVR">OLVR</option>
  <option value="ElectionNight">Election Night</option>
  <option value="Licensing">Licensing</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="NY">New York</option>
  <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
  <option value="MX">Mexico</option>
</select>

<div class="divContainer">
  <div class="NY OLVR">
    <h1>New York OLVR</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="NY ElectionNight">
    <h1>New York Election Night</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="NY Licensing">
    <h1>New York Licensing</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="VT OLVR">
    <h1>Vermont OLVR</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="VT Election Night">
    <h1>Vermont Election Night</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="VT Licensing">
    <h1>Vermont Licensing</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="MX OLVR">
    <h1>Mexico OLVR</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="MX ElectionNight">
    <h1>Mexico Election Night</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="MX Licensing">
    <h1>Mexico Licensing</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above is written on the assumption that you want only those elements with classes from *both* `<select>` elements to show, not all elements with at least one class from either of the `<select>` elements; so you'd want to show only the elements that matched the selector `div.OLVR.NY` *not* all elements that match `div.OLVR` *or* `div.NY`.

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
  - [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).
- jQuery:

  - [`end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/).
  - [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
  - [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
  - [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
  - [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).
  - [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).
  - [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: Yeah, I was partially addressing that in the added (closing) paragraph. The 'Election Night'/'ElectionNight' thing isn't that important, since I took the `value` from the `<option>` not the text (unless I'm missing something, obviously).

Comment: Hi, can you please put the working script and html in codepen and add the link here? I would like to say that I am very bad in javascript. Thank you.

Comment: No, if you want it in Codepen then copy & paste (it's freely available, though if you use it in your project it's best to cite your source to comply with the cc-by-sa Creative Commons license). I wrote it, and explained it; that's pretty much my job done.

Comment: Just do me a favor, please give me the link.

Comment: Copy. Paste. It's not hard, then you can do what you want with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this...

jquery

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#type").change(function() {
        var type = $("#type option:selected" ).val();
        $('.all').css("display", "none");
        $('.' + type).css("display", "block");
    });
    $("#location").change(function() {
        var location = $("#location option:selected" ).val();
        $('.all').css("display", "none");
        $('.' + location).css("display", "block");
    });
});
</script>
```

html

```
<select id="type">
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="OLVR">OLVR</option>
  <option value="ElectionNight">Election Night</option>
  <option value="Licensing">Licensing</option>
</select>

<select id="location">
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="NY">New York</option>
  <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
  <option value="MX">Mexico</option>
</select>

<div class="NY OLVR all">
  <h1>New York OLVR</h1>
</div>

<div class="NY ElectionNight all">
  <h1>New York Election Night</h1>
</div>

<div class="NY Licensing all">
  <h1>New York Licensing</h1>
</div>

<div class="VT OLVR all">
  <h1>Vermont OLVR</h1>
</div>

<div class="VT Election Night all">
  <h1>Vermont Election Night</h1>
</div>

<div class="VT Licensing all">
  <h1>Vermont Licensing</h1>
</div>

<div class="MX OLVR all">
  <h1>Mexico OLVR</h1>
</div>

<div class="MX ElectionNight all">
  <h1>Mexico Election Night</h1>
</div>

<div class="MX Licensing all">
  <h1>Mexico Licensing</h1>
</div>
```

it's not prefect, but it seems like a good place to start.

Comment: Hi, I tried your script it. Thanks for the response. But this does not work. There is some error in the script. I tried applying it in Dreamweaver.

Comment: make sure you're also including jquery on your page <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Hi, I did as you said but nothing happens. Can you please check your code once. Do me a favor, Check this out in codepen and give me the link if it is working. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, just saw this comment now, here's a working codepen > http://codepen.io/zacbeers/pen/XJbOxB